# SMTP - (Google Mail) 550-5.7.26 This message does not pass authentication checks (SPF and DKIM)

Tags: email, smtp, email-server, gmail

I have a working mail server and have been for several years, but I recently changed the server location some place else and as such, it has a different IP for the A record.

I *have* setup the DNS SPF record to have dual IP's to see if that fixes it, but it still doesn't work with Googles Mail server.

```
v=spf1 ip4:12.34.56.78 ip4:78.56.34.12 -all
```

---

Notes:

- My primary A record points to the **first** IP `12.34.56.78`.
- My other A records `mail.`, `smtp.` and `pop.mydomain.com` point to the **second** IP `78.56.34.12`.
- My PTR record points to the **second** IP `78.56.34.12`.
- My MX record is `mydomain.com` pointing to the CNAME `mail.mydomain.com`.
- My TXT record is `v=DMARC1; p=none; adkim=r; aspf=r;`

I have a feeling the A name lookup or reverse lookup is failing since the IP that the email is sent from (in this case, the **first** `12.34.56.78`) ends up being different from the mail server (the **second** IP `78.56.34.12`). I may be incorrect though about that theory so I need the advice of ServerFault members.

I should note that I do *not* use DKIM (yet). Only SPF is present in my DNS.

Any help would be thankful as I've been trying to fix this for about 2 days with no success. I have tried opening a topic on Googles public support system as well, but no one has been able to help me.

Comment: Your question is about sending and for that this will not matter, but MX records point to host names (AAAA and A) and do not reference canonical name records (CNAME).

Comment: Please do not ask about public DNS records omitting the actual name. If I knew the domain, I could run existing tools against it, if I only have a ([inconsistently](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/963/what-information-should-i-include-or-obfuscate-in-my-posts#6063)) obfuscated description, I can only hope I notice it, if the problem is not lost in translation anyway.

Comment: You have not quoted the full status sent by the recipient, e.g. Google would usually go on clarifying what IP address it received the connection from (which could very well be *neither* of the two you intended to use) and a link their documentation.

Comment: No, it's using IPV4 and that's not the issue. `a:hostname` is pointing to the correct A record which is the mail server at `a:mail.mydomain.com.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was just make a new domain specifically used for the email system and all DNS records point to the mail server IP (IE: **78.56.34.12**). That seems to have solved it. I have no idea why it was not working before, but Google must not like having the A record IP different from other A or CNAME records. If I am mistaken, someone can correct me but until then it's fixed itself and I can send to Gmail again.